# Updating library version in Google Colab

Tags: python, statsmodels

Google Colab currently uses version 0.10.2 of the Statsmodels library. However, I want to update this to the latest library of Statsmodels (0.13.0).

```
In[1]: statsmodels.__version__
Out[1]: '0.10.2'
```

The pre-requisits for using the latest version of Statsmodels is upheld by the versions of each library in Colab.
The pre-requisists are:

```
Python >= 3.7
NumPy >= 1.17
SciPy >= 1.3
Pandas >= 1.0
Patsy >= 0.5.2
```

Colab versions:

```
Python 3.7.13
NumPy version: 1.21.6
SciPy version: 1.4.1
Pandas version: 1.3.5
Patsy version: 0.5.2
```

How do I update the library-version in Colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing '!' (apostrophes excluded) at the beginning of the command in Colab, you will run it as if you were running it inside a terminal window and it should be updated in Colab.

Example:

`!pip install statsmodels==0.13.0`

Let me know if this solved your issue. Good luck with your project!